# how to use a script to apply a plug-in filter in photoshop

Tags: photoshop-scripting, plugin

I download "Free Plug-ins" in [flamingpear](http://flamingpear.com/free-trials.html) and put it to: `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2022\Plug-ins\Freebies 64-bit`, then: import  -> Filter -> Flaming Pear -> Solidify C -> export.

**How can I do batch processing with a script (it's an external plugin)?**

Here is an example:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at Actions?

Comment: +1 to Tetsujin, why do you think you need a script for that? Does the plugin requires user input?

Comment: I am not familiar with PS and have seen scripts used to process images before, so I feel that my problems can also be handled using scripts, but using Action seems to be simpler and more convenient. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ICVsi2pWyk&ab_channel=KavinduPasanKavithilaka / https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/save-as-png-script/m-p/6240747]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Tetsujin , we can create new action `Solidify C` to record the operation:
[image]

and the use `Batch` to process the whole folder:
[image]

This seems to be good practice for simple operations.

Comment: You can actually do some pretty complex stuff with Actions, it's similar to recording Macros in other software. Scripting is also possible in Photoshop too. There's a scripListener plugin for Photoshop which you can use to capture the commands that call a plugin, and use them in a script of your own. But scripting is a complex topic.

Comment: OK, thanks.
I used a lot of blender scripts before, so I preconceived that scripts should be used to operate, but I ignored some simpler and more convenient operations in PS.
But the advantage is that the answers given for specific questions help me understand the relevant content, otherwise, as a novice, I may spend a lot of effort to understand the scripting language, while ignoring the more effective way to solve the problem.